# Need help with configuring Mutual Authentication

Tags: authentication

While understanding Mutual Authentication with Salesforce, found the below link, which mentions a option to upload the certificate:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_keys_uploading_mutual_auth_cert.htm&type=0 . 
But in my Salesforce developer organization I don’t see that option. I verified my user has the necessary permission("Customize Application"). What can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open a case in Salesforce support to enable this feature.

[The documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_keys_uploading_mutual_auth_cert.htm&type=0) clearly states that

> If you don’t see this option on the Certificate and Key Management
>   page, contact Salesforce to enable the feature.
>   [image]

However, to have access to Salesforce support, you need to have Premier Support with production user. So you need a production instance or you can ask your employer or your client to open such ticket for you.

We have opened a ticket and after that the link "Upload Mutual Authentication Certificate" has appeared on sandbox instance which organization id we included into ticket.

[image]